# What's wrong with my .htaccess code?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect `www.example.com/ext_jobs/` to `www.example.com/customer/tremoria/ext_jobs/`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/ext_jobs/(.*)$ customer/tremoria/ext_jobs/$1 [L]
```

But my solution is not working. What's wrong?

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the rewritebase instead of the / in `^/ext_jobs/(.*)$`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^customer/tremoria/ext_jobs
RewriteRule ^ext_jobs/(.*)/?$ customer/tremoria/ext_jobs/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use mod-rewrite for simple things. You have simple solutions with mod-alias like Redirect, RedirectMatch and Alias.
In your case I would try a Redirect if you really need a Redirect. But in your sample you are only doing an internal redirect, transparent to the user browser.

So an Alias is maybe the solution

```
Alias ext_jobs/ customer/tremoria/ext_jobs/
```

Comment: very true, I forgot about this one!

Comment: simple but when I try I get an Internal Server Error, why?

Comment: @natalia: maybe I made mistake the second path should be a /full/path/to/customer/tremoria and check that you do have the ending /